# Calculated Column in DAX (Power BI): Fill down formula to add missing information

Tags: dax

Looking for a calculated column to complement missing information in my table. My data looks like this:

[image]

Each article is listed online/offline for a couple of days. I want to extend the online/offline status of each article until the first day it officially changes its status again. Please note that some articles report sales information before they are officially listed online/offline. These blank status fields should be filled out accordlingly as well (see below).

[image]

Thanks in advance -
David

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column that either uses status, if there is one, or uses Sales Date to work out the previous status value

```
Complete Status = 
    VAR PreviousRow =
        TOPN (
            1,
            FILTER (
                Online,
                Online[Sales Date] < EARLIER ( Online[Sales Date] )
            ),
            [Sales Date], DESC
        )
    VAR PreviousValue =
       MINX ( PreviousRow, [Status] )
    
    VAR StatusOrPreviousValue = 
         IF (OR(ISBLANK(Online[Status]), Online[Status]=""),PreviousValue, Online[Status])
    
    RETURN
        StatusOrPreviousValue
```